# Locking WebClient - multithreaded application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, webclient

I have webClient that I am using in my bot:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace Game_Bot
{
    class WebClientEx : WebClient
    {
        public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

        public WebClientEx()
        {
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        }

        public void ClearCookies()
        {
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {

            var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }

}
```

I have one object of my webclient.
There are many methods that use it. If two threads want to use that webClient to download I got error saying that webClent can run only one operation at the time.
How can I modify that class so that when one thread is using it the other one have to wait.
I need to lock it in some way.

Comment: Since you dont want them to run at the same time why not using the queue ? http://www.dotnetperls.com/queue

Comment: @Prix All threads are doing tasks, waiting, counting. Sometimes those thread need to donload some html from page. I Very rare but sometimes happed that 2 threads want to downlad page at the same time. I want to lock that so that only one at the time can use that WebClient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use the lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Mutex for example.
When first client makes a request, you get the property of the mutex, releasing it when the call completes.
When other clients make request, first you wait for mutex and the job is done.